# Custom date cell editor for ag-grid in vue 3 with typescript and <script setup> syntax

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, ag-grid-vue

All the examples in the vue3 ag-grid docs for custom cell editors are based on javascript: https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/component-cell-editor/.
I have an Angular background and there I would create a new component, which implements the ICellEditorAngularComp interface. But in Vue3 it seems to work differently.

How would you implement a custom date cell editor for ag-grid in vue 3 with typescript and  syntax?